# AngularJS pass variable to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

I have to make some directive in an AngularJS app and I need to pass variables from my controller to the directives.

The problem is that I have to use a directive syntax who is not common for me, and I don't know where I have to declare my variable in the directive with this syntax.

Here is my directive :

```
angular
.module('thermofluor')
.directive('tablePlate', tablePlate)

tablePlate.$inject = ['$timeout', '$q'];

function tablePlate( $timeout, $q )
{
var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h1>TEST</h1>'
};

return directive;

function link(scope, element ) {

    return;

}
```

}

Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes my directive is used inside a controller, but how I use the parent scope ?  When I try to show the scope inside the link function it show undefined

Comment: can you explain what do you want to do with a directive? do you have an example of code without directive? you'll use directives to make reusable components and remove repeated codes (js+html)

Comment: I want a directive to create a table of checkbox (12x8) who are activate or desactivate in function of an array of values. My checkboxes will be named in function of their column and line (for example : A1, A2, A3, ...) and in my array I have the name of the checkboxes and the string "activate" or "desactivate"

Answer (score 2):

// see this example of code to understand ho to use directives

```
// directive example
angular.module('thermofluor').directive('tablePlate', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        arrayOfChecks: '='
    },
    template: '<h1>TEST</h1>' + htmlTable,
    link:  function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

    }
}
});

var htmlTable = 
'<table>' +
'   <tr>' +
'       <th>Name</th>' +
'       <th>Value</th>' +
'       <th>Active</th>' +
'   </tr>' +
'   <tr ng-repeat="c in arrayOfChecks">' +
'       <td>{{c.name}}</td>' +
'       <td>{{c.value</td>' +
'       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="c.active"></td>' +
'   </tr>' +
'</table>';

// controller
angular.module('thermofluor').controller('myController',  function(){
$scope.myListOfChecks = [{name: 'A', value:'A value', active: false},
                    {name: 'B', value:'B value', active: true},
                    {name: 'C', value:'C value', active: false},
                    {name: 'D', value:'D value', active: true}];
});

// html

<div class="row" ng-controller="myController">

<table-plate array-of-checks="myListOfChecks"></table-plate>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to modifiy some values with the link function, how can I do that ? When I try to use scope.arrayOfChecks it return me a $$state object

Comment: add this lines 
// on table
 <th>Button</th>

 <td><button ng-click="editValue(c)">Edit Value</button></td>

// this code in directive
link:  function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
 scope.editValue = function(selectedRow){
  selectedRow.value = 'New Value';
 }
}

Comment: @Jessy did you try it?